# Using a JTable as a JList

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable of data. I want it so that when a row is selected, an event can occur. With a JList, I would simply add a ListSelectionListener. Any way to do this with a JTable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use your ListSelectionListener with JTable too (take a look at the JavaDocs of [ListSelectionListener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html): JTable also implements it, so you would use it like for your JList).

[See an example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/SelEvent.html) (but if you already used it with JList, than you know how to use use it with JTable too).

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't see that before. Thanks!